# Resizing a table column individually in HTML

Tags: html

[Task of the html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VC0gR.png)

[The code that I made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGJR6.png)

[Result of the code that I made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngTlZ.png)

I only have to resize the "Properties" column of the table to 70% but now it resizes both of them. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Links to external code is not reliable -- SO requires questions to have a [mcve] when it's possible.

Comment: Kindly provide sample code format in question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that this helps you

```css
.propertiesTH {
    width: 70%
}

th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>List</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th class="propertiesTH" colspan="2">Properties</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Username</td>
                <td>50</td>
                <td>Male</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Username 2</td>
                <td>50</td>
                <td>Female</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```